# Golang заполнить массив байт фиксированного размера из 16-ричной строки

Tags: golang

Я хочу реализовать криптогарфические преобразования из гостовского шифра и написать юнит-тесты для контрольных примеров. Первое преобразование простое:

```
package main

const BlockSize = 16

type Block [BlockSize]byte

func GostX(a, b, c *Block) {
    for i := 0; i < BlockSize; i++ {
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]
    }
}
```

Надо протестировать сложение двоичных векторов. По контрольным примерам из стандарта я написал такой юнит-тест:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "testing"
)

func TestGostX(t *testing.T) {
    c, _ := hex.DecodeString("6ea276726c487ab85d27bd10dd849401")
    k, _ := hex.DecodeString("8899aabbccddeeff0011223344556677")
    expected, _ := hex.DecodeString("e63bdcc9a09594475d369f2399d1f276")

    var result [16]byte
    GostX(c, k, result[:])
    if !bytes.Equal(result[:], expected) {
        t.Errorf("GostX was incorrect, got %x, want %x.", result, expected)
    }
}
```

Но я не знаю, как заполнить массив байт фиксированного размера 16 данными типа "слайс". Слайс возвращает функция преобразования 16-ричного числа в массив байт (все контрольные примеры даны в хексах). Как это сделать технически?

В криптосистеме все вычисления выполняются над блоками байт и отдельными байтами. Но если на си это делается просто, то в го мешает система типов и мое незнание языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Go 2.0 есть [предложение](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/395) добавить возможность конвертировать слайс в указатель на массив. Пока же, можно либо проделать танцы с `unsafe`, либо использовать [`copy`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy). Во втором варианте ваш юнит-тест выглядит так:

```golang
func TestGostX(t *testing.T) {
    cSl, _ := hex.DecodeString("6ea276726c487ab85d27bd10dd849401")
    kSl, _ := hex.DecodeString("8899aabbccddeeff0011223344556677")
    expSl, _ := hex.DecodeString("e63bdcc9a09594475d369f2399d1f276")

    var c, k, exp, res Block

    copy(c[:], cSl)
    copy(k[:], kSl)
    copy(exp[:], expSl)

    GostX(&c, &k, &res)
    if res != exp {
        t.Errorf("GostX was incorrect, got %x, want %x.", res, exp)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/KC7XZfd8mR7.

(Заметьте, массивы можно сравнивать напрямую.)